# Why is my furnace limit tripping?

Tags: furnace

My furnace is tripping the high limit.  It is a Downflow Payne 90+ have replaced the limit switch. I pulled the blower door off and checked all vents to ensure they are open and it still short cycles.  I also changed the speed on the blower and checked gas pressure.  I'm stumped!  Does anyone have any ideas as to what's going on?

Comment: You checked the exhaust vent for blockages?

Comment: Have you changed the filter, and checked for inflow restrictions? Are you sure it's the high limit?

Comment: Yes like i said had blower door off. if exhaust vent was blocked would b press switch right

Comment: 99.9% of the time high limit trips are airflow problems. Check for dirty filter, clogged/dirty blower wheel, closed dampers, blocked vents (supply and return), etc. If you have an inducer motor, exhaust flow should trip the pressure sensor not the limit. However, in the unlikely event that the pressure switch has failed closed, that would be a problem.

Comment: What is the model number of your furnace?  Do you have the owners manual?

Comment: Did you replace the limit switch with an approved replacement part? Was the replacement an adjustable model, that you did not adjust?

Comment: Have u by chance changed out your thermostat recently?

Comment: I have seen this problem when the blower motor is not doing its job from loose belts and or bearings that need lubrication. Usually a few drops of oil at the blower motor oil points can free up the bearings and give a few more years of life, other than that closed vents and dirty filters are the problems I have found or crushed flex lines.

Answer (score 1):

The only way the plenum can get hot enough to hit the high limit is lack of air flow.
Open all registers and dampers and take the filter out.
If it still gets too hot your central air "A" 
coil may be plugged with dirt.

Comment: Yeah -- if the A coil is clean and your furnace is still cycling on the high-limit, then I'd check for a blower failure or excess duct static.